# Is it possible to send a b c d ... characters over USSD protocol

Tags: ussd

As far as I know we can send numbers and some characters like * and # over USSD but I want to send other characters and words like "Test". Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

A USSD message can contain upto 182 alphanumeric characters.

This includes letters, and you can test this out by simply checking your balance or services on your mobile. Almost all the USSD responses sent by the carrier contain letters.

Comment: Yes, but I asked about USSD request, Is it possible to send letters using USSD by phone

Comment: If you're sending it manually, then yes. Most dialpads won't let you type them in. Should be possible programatically.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes/no. USSD supports all kinds of characters, you can not only send a,b,c,d but also in other languages but it is generally limited to the responses by the users and messages from your service operator. However, While dialing a short code(eg *123*12#) you cannot include these characters(a,b,c..), because generally the operators just uses the numbers to define their services as per the standards and hence does not allow use of other characters.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, you can. In GSM modules with AT command interface you do so with the AT+CUSD command and get answers with the +CUSD unsolicited result code. Android phones seem to lack an API for that, but [workaround code](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285#c257) seems possible.